# How can I show the custom parametrs in User Report in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js, google-analytics-4

I would like to show the custom parameters values in the User Report *(next image)*.

[Click to see where I need to show the parameters in Google Analytics 4 User Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJQQn.png)

I have created the event with this code:

```
gtag('event', 'stop',  {
      page_title: myTitle,
      page_location: myPage
      timeView : timeView
});
```

Comment: Beside you have to enable them in "Custom Definition"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable custom parameters in the interface before you can use them.

Alternatively, if you've linked GA4 Stream to BigQuery, you can find them there.